# JQuery on click display Save Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a simple profile linked to our company database, in which clients can log in and check their details.  Basically, I need a function that will display a Save button when the edit button is clicked.  As soon as I press cancel, the save button should disappear again.

I am a bit of a noob, so maybe I am missing something very simple, for which I apologise.  The code and JSFiddle follow:

http://jsfiddle.net/65D9C/26/

```
<HTML>
<button src="#" id="littleButton">Edit Profile</button>

<div id="button-sm">
    <input type="submit" class="ButtonSm" value="Save" id="save_button" name="save_button"></input>
</div>
</HTML>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var SaveButton = $('#button-sm');
    $(SaveButton).hide();
    $('#littleButton').onclick(function (e) {
        $(SaveButton).animate({
            'opacity': 'toggle'
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hey. Well the trigger is click - jQuery("#id").click(function(e){});

if you are using jQuery 1.10.1 or over, i would suggest you use
jQuery("#id").on("click",function (e){});

because apparently they have been migrating the code to 'on'/'off'. I had some issues with other triggers. So its something for the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working Demo : **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ricksmarty/c94vV/)**

It should be `click` event not onclick also you have to include jQuery library you can download from here **[jQuery 1.11.1](http://jquery.com/download/)**

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var SaveButton = $('#button-sm');
      SaveButton.hide();
    $('#littleButton').click(function (e) {
        SaveButton.animate({
            'opacity': 'toggle'
        });
    });
});
```

For more info about click event see [**jQuery click event**](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: Thanks man, this works great.  even kept the opacity which is what I wanted too.

Comment: glad it works for you please mark this answer as accepted if you got the solution [How to accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) @SydHolmes

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems in your code. First of all should be [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) instead of `onclick`.

See the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var SaveButton = $('#button-sm');
    SaveButton.hide();
    $('#littleButton').click(function (e) {
        SaveButton.show();
    });
});
```

Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/65D9C/27/)

Comment: The animate opacity  method will work  , just look this link http://jsfiddle.net/65D9C/35/

Answer (score 0):

You did `not include any jquery` and also there is no  `onclick` in jquery .so you have to use `click` event

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var SaveButton = $('#button-sm');
      SaveButton.hide();
    $('#littleButton').click(function (e) {
        SaveButton.animate({
            'opacity': 'toggle'
        });
    });
});
```

### [Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/65D9C/33/)

Answer (score 0):

there is click event not onclcik

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    var SaveButton = $('#button-sm');
    SaveButton.hide();
    $('#littleButton').on('click',function (e) {
        SaveButton.show();
    });
});
```

and you didn't include js in your fiddle.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/65D9C/31/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this : use `click` instead of `onclick` and you can use `show("slow")` to display show button

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var SaveButton = $('#button-sm');
    $(SaveButton).hide();
    $('#littleButton').click(function (e) {
        var buttonLbl = "Edit Profile";
        if($(this).text()!="Cancel")
            buttonLbl="Cancel";
        $(this).text(buttonLbl);
        $(SaveButton).toggle('slow');
    });
 });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/65D9C/37/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this (and sorry for my awful english)

**JS - section**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#littleButton').on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#button-sm").fadeIn(300);
    });

    $('#cancelButton').on("click", function(e){
        $("#button-sm").fadeOut(300);
    });
});
```

This jQuery show your SAVE button when you click on "EDIT" button and hide you button if you click on a "CANCEL" button (with id "cancelButton")

But you have to set this in your css first of all

**CSS section**

```
#button-sm {
    display:none;
}
```